# How can i insert a css snippet using javascript base on the choices of the user

Tags: javascript, css

I have this HTML and Javascript code. But how can i execute a specific CSS base on the choices below?

For example:

1. Platform = Unix, Windows, Network = Execute CSS1
2. Platform = Unix, Windows = Execute CSS2

I don't have any idea how to get the values to be exported to the css. Please add or correct my code if you saw any issues. I can't add my HTML code here i don't know why so i will just link it.

Here is my HTML-Code:

```
<div>Platform</div> 
<input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Unix">Unix
<input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Windows">Windows
<input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Network">Network<br><br>
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="SubmitClicked()" id="go" value="Submit">
```

[image]

```
function SubmitClicked(){

    var platform = $("input[name='platform']:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();    
    var csscode="CSS";

    if(platform=="Unix,Windows,Network"){
        csscode="CSS2";
    }
    if(platform=="Unix,Windows"){
        csscode="CSS3";
    }
    if(platform=="Unix,Network"){
        csscode="CSS4";
    }
    if(platform=="Windows,Network"){
        csscode="CSS5";
    }
    if(platform=="Unix"){
        csscode="CSS6";
    }
    if(platform=="Windows"){
        csscode="CSS7";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it slightly differently than what @SteffPoint is suggesting.

I would set up all my CSS as different classes in a single stylesheet, and make sure that stylesheet is loaded on the page where you want it applied. (You can do that in various ways - Script Editor Webpart, Content Editor Webpart, etc - whatever works for you.)

So something like

```
.class-1 {
    /* styles for all three selected */
}

.class-2 {
    /* styles for Unix & Windows selected */
}

.class-3 {
    /* styles for Unix & Netwrok selected */
}

/* etc... */
```

Then, in your javascript code, do something like

```
function SubmitClicked(){

    var platform = $("input[name='platform']:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();    

    if(platform=="Unix,Windows,Network"){
        $('selector-to-get-calendar-webpart').addClass('class-1');
    }
    if(platform=="Unix,Windows"){
        $('selector-to-get-calendar-webpart').addClass('class-2');
    }
    if(platform=="Unix,Network"){
        $('selector-to-get-calendar-webpart').addClass('class-3');
    }

    // etc...
}
```

The point is, you're not dynamically *adding* CSS per-se - all of your CSS options are pre-loaded on the page already, they're just not applied to anything.

Then, when the user makes their choice, you dynamically *apply* the CSS by adding the appropriate class to the appropriate HTML element.

Comment: I have to admit, that your answer is more efficient than mine. The only reason for me keeping the stylesheets externally and generally deciding for this "workaroundy" way was to have at least some SharePoint context when hosting them in the Site Assets for example ;)

Comment: Thank you Dylan it worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can use the result of `window.navigator` to find information about the used OS.

```
console.log(window.navigator);
```

Then you can use a code like following (Following Code recognizes if your OS is XP or different and puts specific CSS as consequence - just customize it to your requirements):

```
function changeStyle() {
var css = document.createElement('link');
css.rel="stylesheet";
css.type = 'text/css';

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Windows NT 5.1")!=-1){ /* IF is windowsXP */
css.href = 'styleXP.css';
} else {
css.href = 'style7.css';
}

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
return false;
}
```

I would locate the different CSS files in the Site Assets of your SharePoint. Simply change the `href value` to the url of the located files.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774009/os-specific-css

---

**Update:**

I have created you a sample Code (only for checkbox "Unix" so far) to load a specific CSS when the checkbox is checked. As little help I have added a text which shows if a CSS is loaded or not. You can of course remove it :)

```
<div>Platform</div> 
<input id="platform" onclick="functionUnix()" type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Unix">Unix
<input id="platform2" type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Windows">Windows
<input id="platform3" type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Network">Network<br><br>
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="SubmitClicked()" id="go" value="Submit">



<p id="text" style="display:none">CSS for Unix is loaded</p>

<script>
function functionUnix() {
  var css = document.createElement('link');
  css.rel="stylesheet";
  css.type = 'text/css';
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("platform");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
    css.href = 'LinkToYourUNIXStyleSheet.css';
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
return false;

}
</script>
```

Comment: I'll be using this on a calendar in sharepoint and what i mean by platform is a column that the user will choose from. I'm changing the CSS of the calendar base on the choices of the user. I hope i make it clear

Comment: @JunTan: Sorry, I got your question wrong. Now I know what exactly your requirements are. I have written you a tiny Code sample (see my updated answer). Please mind, that I have only added the functionality to one checkbox. For the other two checkboxes it basically works the same way. Just make sure, that you give the functions and the element unique `ID`s. If you have any further questions, please come back to me ;)